# Testing Directive Link Function, Spying on $watch?

Tags: angularjs, testing, karma-jasmine

I have a question on testing a directive.

Here is a copy of my directive

```
angular.module('dashboard').directive('gradientBar', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div class="bar"><div id="change_arrow"></div><div class="bar-fill"></div><div class="bar-ref"></div></div>',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        'min': '=',
        'max': '=',
        'val': '=',
        'avg': '=',
        'prev': '=',
    },

    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('val', function() {

            var ref_current = Math.round((scope.val - scope.min) * 100 / (scope.max - scope.min));

            if (scope.prev) {

                var ref_prev = Math.round((scope.prev - scope.min) * 100 / (scope.max - scope.min));
                if (ref_current - ref_prev >= 1) {

                    element.find('#change_arrow').addClass('expand-button up_dark');
                    element.find('.bar-ref').css('left', ref_prev + "%");

                } else if (ref_current - ref_prev <= -1){
                    element.find('#change_arrow').addClass('expand-button down_dark');
                    element.find('.bar-ref').css('left', ref_prev + "%");
                } else {
                    element.find('.bar-ref').css('display', 'none');
                }

            } else if (scope.avg) {
                var ref_avg = Math.round((scope.avg - scope.min) * 100 / (scope.max - scope.min));
                element.find('.bar-ref').css('left', ref_avg + "%");

            } else {
                element.find('.bar-ref').css('display', 'none');
            }

            var width = (scope.val - scope.min) / (scope.max - scope.min);
            element.find('.bar-fill').css('width', ref_current + "%").css('background', colorify(width));

        });
    }
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to test the link function in this directive...I've figured out how to pull the values in isolateScope() to ensure they are being updated appropriately, but I haven't figured out to spy on or confirm that the various branches in my link function execute and apply the correct classes to elements in Template.

Any guidance would be very appreciated. I feel like I've been reading up on this topic for most of the day, and am still struggling to figure out an answer...

EDIT:

I just tried to append the element below to the body of my DOM, and it doesn't look like the link function was applied at all to my template element...unsure as to why.

EDIT:

Here is my test setup. I'm using Karma and Jasmine:

```
    describe('gradientBar.js Unit Tests', function(){
    var $compile, scope, element, isolatedScope;

    beforeEach(module('dashboard')); //the module of the file under test

    beforeEach(module('partialsCacheHaml')); 

        // scope.$digest();
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$compile_) {

        $compile = _$compile_;
        scope = _$rootScope_;

        elementT = angular.element('<gradient_bar min="min" max="max" val="val" prev="prev" avg="avg"></gradient_bar>');

        scope.min = 0;
        scope.max = 4;
        scope.val = 2;
        scope.prev = false;
        scope.avg = false;
        scope.should_not_be_accessible_in_isolated_scope = '111';

        element = $compile(elementT)(scope);

        spyOn(element, 'find')

        isolatedScope = element.isolateScope();

        scope.$digest();

    }));

    it(' IsolatedScope contains the appropriate bindings', function(){

        expect(isolatedScope.min).toBe(0);
        expect(isolatedScope.max).toBe(4);
        expect(isolatedScope.val).toBe(2);
        expect(isolatedScope.prev).toBe(false);
        expect(isolatedScope.avg).toBe(false);
        expect(isolatedScope.should_not_be_accessible_in_isolated_scope).toBe(undefined);   

    });

    it(' After compilation, element contains the appropriate html tags', function(){

        expect(element.html()).toContain('<div id="change_arrow"></div>');
        expect(element.html()).toContain('<div class="bar-fill"></div>');
        expect(element.html()).toContain('<div class="bar-ref"></div>');

    });

    it(' updates rootScope when values in isolatedScope are updated', function(){
        //this is due to the '='' declaration in the isolated scope of the directive
        isolatedScope.min = 20;
        isolatedScope.max = 20;
        isolatedScope.val = 20;
        isolatedScope.prev = 20;
        isolatedScope.avg = 20;

        isolatedScope.$digest();
        expect(isolatedScope.min).toBe(20);
        expect(scope.min).toBe(20);
        expect(isolatedScope.max).toBe(20);
        expect(scope.max).toBe(20);     
        expect(isolatedScope.val).toBe(20);
        expect(scope.val).toBe(20);     
        expect(isolatedScope.prev).toBe(20);
        expect(scope.prev).toBe(20);        
        expect(isolatedScope.avg).toBe(20);
        expect(scope.avg).toBe(20);
    });

    it(' sets the .bar-fill width parameter to the %away from the difference between min and max of val', function(){

        var val_param = Math.round((isolatedScope.val - isolatedScope.min) * 100 / (isolatedScope.max - isolatedScope.min));

    })

    it(' adds the expand-button up_dark class to #change_arrow when the percentage difference between val and prev is greater than 1', function(){

    });

    it(' adds the expand-button down_dark class to #change_arrow when the percentage difference between val and prev is less than -1', function(){

    });

    it(' adds the left = xx% value to the .bar-ref div if prev does not exist (is false) and avg exists', function(){

    });

    it(' adds the display=none property to the .bar-ref div if prev does not exist and avg does not exist', function(){

    });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use jQuery in your `link` function. Instead, use the built in directives in your template. For instance things like:

```
<div class="bar">
  <div class="bar-arrow" ng-class="getClass()"></div>
  <div class="bar-fill"  ng-style="getStyle()"></div>
  <div class="bar-ref"   ng-show="isVisible()"></div>
</div>
```

And then create the correspoding `getClass`, `getStyle`, `isVisible` fucntions in your `link`, that would be more robust and clean.

Now for a way to test that, the real answer would be to cover it by Karma or Protractor test suites, but if you want to have a look at what's wrong from your browser, you can try:

```
var elem = $('.bar') // get the directive root element
var scope = elem.isolateScope();
scope.val = 42;
scope.$digest();
```

And in your $watch add some log such as `console.log('New val is', val)`.

Comment: I'm using karma / Jasmine to test. This is where I want to write my tests that the link function is working as expected, and my element is getting the correct classes applied to it (per the logic in the link function).
in my tests, however, after i element = $compile(<gradient_bar></gradient_bar>)(scope), if I console.log(element) the html is the same as the directive template that I pass in to be compiled / linked. I'm trying to see what the HTML looks like after the link function executes. Any advice?

Comment: Are you sure you passed a "val" in parameter? Be sure to apply your scope in the test, and potentially add a timeout before you check the compiled HTML. I'm not very familiar with Karma so not sure how it process the scope cycle. And if you don't either, I would first test the directive directly in a browser by yourself, and then write a regression test to make sure it keep doing that. But it's easier to validate the directive by having a quick loo at it.

Comment: Yeah the directive works as i'm expecting it to in the browser...these tests are just to ensure good coverage.

I am sure I am passing a val. I have some tests that check that my isolated scope is updated appropriately.

Comment: Well if the directive works as espected in the browser then you should include the test in your question and add the `Karma` tag. I cannot help you further.

Comment: I wound up refactoring my code to use the ngHide and ngStyle directives...it made the testability sooooo much better!